# How to filter data by dimension in a netCDF file

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset, netcdf, netcdf4

Using python, I have imported a netCDF file using the netCDF4 library...

```
import netCDF4 as nc
ncObject = nc.Dataset('somefile.nc')
```

Here are the dimensions of the ncObject…

```
fov(9)
y(100)
x(100)
pressure(100)
cloud_layers(2)
```

What I'm trying to do is filter the dataset by dimension or series of dimensions.  So basically I want my new ncObject to only include records where fov=0 and cloud_layers=0.  I know this can be done using the xarray module with the code seen below, but I would like to do the same thing using the netCDF4 package (reason being that netCDF4 works better with accessing nested variables within group folders)...

```
ncObjectNew = ncObject.sel(cloud_layers=0).sel(fov=0)
```

Curious if anyone knows how to write the above using the netCDF4 notation/syntax.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

This `make_subsets` function should help you:

```
import netCDF4 as nc

def make_subsets(variables, ranges):
    """
    Inputs:
      variables: dict with key: var name, value: netCDF variable
      ranges: dict with key: dim name, value: 2-tuple of (start, stop) indices
    Returns:
      variables subsetted according to the supplied ranges, in same format as 
      the input variables dictionary
    """
    subsets = {}
    for varname, v in variables.items():
        subset_args = []
        if v.shape:
            for size, dim in zip(v.shape, v.dimensions):
                if dim in ranges:
                    subset_args.append(slice(*ranges[dim]))
                else:
                    subset_args.append(slice(0, size))
            print(subset_args)
            subsets[varname] = v.__getitem__(subset_args)
        else:
            # scalar                                                                                
            subsets[varname] = v
    return subsets


ncObject = nc.Dataset('somefile.nc')

# start and end values for every dimension we want to subset                                        
# (as usual, end value is the index AFTER the last element wanted)                                  
ranges = {'fov': (0, 1), 'cloud_layers': (0, 1)}

subsets = make_subsets(ncObject.variables, ranges)

for varname, v in subsets.items():
    print(varname, v.shape)
```

---

Update: I have interpreted the above question to mean that `fov=0` and `cloud_layers=0` refer to the requested **dimension indices** (integers).  These are then used by the `slice` operator in the normal way. In the above example, the `'fov': (0, 1)` means that in the `fov` dimension the slice `[0:1]` will be used (i.e. only include element with index `0`; stop before element with index `1`).  I hope this clarifies what I am providing.

If the aim is to specify the **values** of some coordinate variables with the same name (defined such as `float fov(fov)`), then the inputs would need to be pre-processed to obtain the corresponding indices (with some decision about what to do if there is not an exact match).

Apologies if I have misinterpreted the question, but given the passage of time, I don't intend to revise the answer at this stage, only to clarify what question I thought I was trying to answer.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar but I need to return values between a min\max lat\long. I modified the ranges = {'fov': (0, 1), 'cloud_layers': (0, 1)} to ranges = {'lat': (minlat, maxlat), 'long': (minlong, maxlong)} I didn't get an error but I also didn't get a list of expected values. How does the ranges = {'fov': (0, 1), 'cloud_layers': (0, 1)} work exactly?

Comment: @alani should provide an explanation why we should use his code.

Comment: @MrKingsley, the slicing of the nc dataset works with indici. Therefor, you need to know what the index is of the minlat and maxlat within the dimension 'Latitude'.

Comment: @MrKingsley I have now added some words of explanation to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function to create a masking array, that can be used to fancy index the correct subsample.

```
def within(arr, origin, dx):
    """Given an array, mask all values outside dx around origin."""
    try:
        return np.absolute(arr.data - origin) <= dx
    except TypeError:
        return np.absolute(arr - origin) <= dx
```

If you pass the `latitude` or `longitude` (or any other) dimension array, it will return a boolean array of True where the dimension is within the specified limit.

For example:

```
Latitude = file['dimensions/Latitude'][:]
>> Latitude = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
within(Latitude, origin=3, dx=1)
>> [False, False, True, True, True, False]  # np.array or np.ma.masked_array

Longitude = file['dimensions/Longitude'][:] 
>> Longitude = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]  # np.array or np.ma.masked_array
within(Longitude, origin=11, dx=1)
>> [True, True, True, False, Fasle]
```

You can then use it to slice your dataset array

```
# fov = fov(9)  # extract the dimension array
# cloud_layers = cloud_layers(2)    # extract the dimension array
ncObject[within(fov, 0, 0), :, :, :, within(cloud_layers, 0, 0)]
```